# Prove that $A^5 \neq I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

$A \in M_{5}(\mathbb{C})$, $\operatorname{trace}(A) = 0$, $I-A$ is invertible. Prove that $A^5 \neq I$

I think this problem has something to do with eigenvalue and the fact that trace of a matrix = sum of the eigenvalues. But, I have no idea how to proceed!

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: If $I-A$ is invertible $A$ can't have one as an eigenvalue...

Comment: If $A^5=I$ then $A$ is diagonalisable. If $I-A$ is invertible, then $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am new to diagonalizability. How come $A^5 =I$ infer $A$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: A matrix is diagonalizable if the minimum polynomial has roots of multeplicity one. If $A^5 = I$ then the minimum polynomial of $A$ divides $x^5-1$ that has distinct roots.

Comment: @astrobarrel if A-B is invertible. Is B-A invertible ?

Comment: Of course it is - you don't change independence of the columns of a matrix if you multiply by a constant

Comment: @astrobarrel unless the constant is $0$ :-)

Comment: You also need to use the fact that $A$ is a $5\times5$ matrix in particular. It is easy to construct a $4\times4$ matrix $A$ such that $tr(A)=0$, $I-A$ is invertible and $A^5=I$. Hint: Do you know from field theory what the minimal polynomial (over $\Bbb{Q}$) of the fifth roots of unity is? If that was all Greek to you, do tell! I will try and come up with another hint in that case.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen All greek !!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume, by the way of contradiction, that $A^5 = I$ holds. In this case, as $A^5 - I = 0$, we can factorize this expression in $(A - I)(A^4 + A^3 + A^2 + A + I) =0 $.

As $A - I $ is invertible, the first factor is nonzero, hence the last one is and the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides it, forcing  $A$ to have all eigenvalues being fifth roots of 1, but distinct from 1 because  $A-I $ is invertible. Now, since  $tr (A) = 0$, the sum of all eigenvalues must be zero. Can you see now that, no matter what is the multiplicity of each eigenvalue, if no eigenvalue is 1 it is impossible to sum them all and have 0? It leads to a contradiction, then.

Comment: +1 (a nice first post) I want to emphasize that it is important that there are five eigenvalues, counted with multiplicity.

Comment: This answer is generally correct, but the last argument is not so obvious. One needs to cooperate @Jyrki's comment on the size of $A$ above.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How can you ensure that there will be 5 eigen values ?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you had $A^5 = I$. Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are all fifth roots of unity. The fact that $I - A$ is invertible means that $1$ is not an eigenvalue. So you're left with the other $4$ fifth roots of unity.

You're given that the trace of $A$ is zero, so the sum of all eigenvalues of zero. So if you can verify that there's no way of adding the remaining fifth roots of unity to get zero then you're done. But any such way would result in an equation
$$c_3e^{8\pi i \over 5} + c_2e^{6\pi i \over 5} +c_1e^{4\pi i \over 5} + c_0e^{2\pi i \over 5} = 0$$
Here the $c_i$ are integers. So $z = e^{2\pi i \over 5}$ satisfies 
$$c_3z^3 + c_2z^2 + c_1z + c_0 = 0 \tag{*}$$
But $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is the minimal polynomial of $z$ ( since cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible.) Hence $(*)$ cannot happen and thus the assumption that $A^5 = I$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: How can you say that $A^5 = I$. Then the eigenvalues of A are all fifth roots of unity ?

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector then $Av = \lambda v$ for its eigenvalue $\lambda$. Iterating gives $A^5v = \lambda^5 v$. So if $A^5 = I$ then $v = \lambda^5v$ so that $\lambda^5 = 1$.